# Enable text boxes and buttons using status

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am filling the data for education details. I  load status from database.

- When  the emp click on the edit button it will show the enable is true (`in status !=1`).
- `if status is ==1` ,and emp click on edit button enable status  is false . i write the condition but it not 
  work.

Please give me some suggestions ..

```
if (exenewRow.Status != 1 && logUser.UserType == 1)
{ 
    divStatus.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    divStatus.EnableViewState = false;
    ddlStatus.Enabled = false;
    btnSubmit.Visible = true;
    txtPreviousCompany.ReadOnly = true;
    txtFromDate.Enabled = false;
    txtToDate.Enabled = false;
    txtNatOFWork.ReadOnly = true;
    txtRegion.ReadOnly = true;
} 
mvExperience.SetActiveView(mvAddEditExperience);
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @mahisoft `divStatus.EnableViewState = false;` Why this ?And do you want to hide `Div` ?

Answer (score 0):

By default set text boxes and buttons enabled false.
then check

```
if(status == 1)
{

    ButtonId.Enabled=true;
    TextBoxId.Enabled=true;
}
```

this will definitely gonna works.

Did you used update panel in your page?

If yes then set trigger on which you are firing this method.`enter code here`

Comment: Reformatted your code, please use the button {} to correctly format code text